# How to build an xml tree using an event based parsers in perl for a huge data?

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file like this:

```
    <Nodes><Node>
 <NodeName>Company</NodeName>
 <File>employee_details.csv</File>
 <data>employee_data.txt</data>
<Node>
     <NodeName>dummy</NodeName>
     <File>employee_details1.csv</File>
     <data>employee_data1.txt</data>
    </Node>
    </Node>
</Nodes>

    #Contents of employee_data.txt
Empname,Empcode,EmpSal:Currency,Empaddr
#Contents of employee_details.csv (like this huge data)
Alex,A001,1000:USD,Bangalore
Aparna,B001,1000:RUBEL,Bombay
#Contents of employee_data1.txt
phone,fax
#Contents of employee_details1.csv (like this huge data)
44568889,123345656
23232323,454545757
```

Output:

```
<Company>
<Empname>Alex</Empname>
<Empcode>A001</Empcode>
<EmpSal=USD>1000</EmpSal>
<Empaddr>Bangalore</Empaddr>
<phone>44568889</phone>
<fax>123345656</fax>
</Company>
<Company>
<Empname>Aparna</Empname>
<Empcode>B001</Empcode>
<EmpSal=RUBEL>1000</EmpSal>
<Empaddr>Bombay</Empaddr>
<phone>23232323</phone>
<fax>454545757</fax>
```

I want to build an XML tree with Sax parser but I am not able to understand how to traverse across all the nodes and create an event.

I should get the above output?

How can I do it in Perl?

Answer (score 2):

.pl file
my $factory = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->new();
my $parser = $factory->parser( Handler =>sax_handler->new(arguments_to parse));

sax_handler.pm
su new()
{
//nothing as such !
   my ($type);
   return bless {}, $type;
}
//follwong 2 methods are important
sub start_element 
{
    my ($self, $element) = @_;

```
#attributes of comment tag...m:text is tag
if( $element->{Name} eq "m:text")
{
$name=$element->{Attributes}->{'{}name'}->{'Value'};
}
```

}

//m:reviewID is tag in u r xml !
sub end_element 
{
    my ($self, $element) = @_;

```
#write down all tags...& print them or manipulate them
if( $element->{Name} eq "m:reviewID"){
```

}
}

Comment: m:text means? I have starting element as <Nodes> and m:reviewID means what. I have to get the data from the files but there is no such fuction seen here .... if u can brief little bit more that would be really great....

Comment: hey, "m:text" & "m:review_id" are the tags present in the xml which I'm parsing...You can replace it with "Empname" & "Empcode" etc. You can refer below url:- "http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Perl/Using-Perl-with-XML-part-1/6/" [really nice] or ping me for any issues.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the CSV files can be huge, not the XML one. So really there is no need to use a SAX parser. The XML is used only to give you the location of 4 files. 2 of those files (the `.txt` ones) are small, they only contain a list of fields, and the last 2 files can be big. Those are the CSV file.

You should use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV_XS/) to parse those 2 huge file. You can then output the XML using plain print (just make sure you escape the text and pay attention to the encoding (BTW in your sample output `<EmpSal=USD>` is not well-formed XML, the attribute value needs to be quoted:  `<EmpSal="USD">`). An other options is [XML::Writer](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Writer/), which will take care of escaping and quoting for you. I don't think generating SAX events and passing them to a SAX writer makes sense in this case, it would be more complex and probably slower than the other options.

Comment: The csv file creation are handled by procedures for me the important is XML handling. How can i do that?

Comment: in this situation, it looks like XML::Simple would be enough to read the XML file into a Perl data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Well SAX Parser is slightly different from other parsing techniques. Here you need to write your handler [ perl module]. module must contains following things -> 1. constructor. 2. subroutine start_element 3.end_element. You can manage events inside the subroutines like this [for  tag] -->if( $element->{Name} eq "mail_id"){
        $user_mail_id=$self->get_text();}

Comment: Do i need to use for each element or in general how to get the main root node and get the children of that and substitute the value. It will be very help full if an event handler is written in this scenario? code will be very helpful because i am stuck up there in handling the event and proceeding towards the output as mentioned above?

Comment: one question ? why you need SAX, have you tried DOM ? I'll send the code snippet for SAX handler!

Comment: yes i have tried with the dom for 9000 records the xml creation is taking around 3 mins. So thats the reason i want to try with Sax one question what about libxml in this case? Please do send the code snippet for SAX handler will be really helpfull